# Drools Compound OR rule in Excel sheet

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor

I have thousands of rules written in excel sheets so I can't easily move away from that unless there is a good reason.  Also using version 5 of Drools and cannot easily upgrade.  Using Drools Guvnor for managing and compiling rules.

I have the need to write a massive compound rule and I am struggling on how to do it.

Facts:  width, length, part number

Rule need to be written:

```
   for a specific part number
        outside of dim range w1 x l1 then can't use Adaptor1
        outside of dim range w2 x l2 then can't use Adaptor2
        outside of dim range w3 x l3 then can't use Adaptor2
        outside of dim range w4 x l4 then can't use Adaptor3
        if no adaptor can be used then you can't use Base1
```

I need to know which Adaptors are not allowed and which Bases are not allowed.

Any ideas on how this can be written in an excel sheet.

Comment: Here's a good reason to move away from excel sheets: they're super super resource intensive and (compared to native drls) super super slow.

Comment: Also I upgraded from 5.0.1 to 7.44.0. It's not that hard. If I can do it, you can too. ;)

Comment: Also I really hope you're already aware that you can use both DRL and decision tables at the same time ....